# Error in a simple cuda compilation

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu

FSPB_main.cpp

```
int main(int args, char* argv[]){    
    .......   

   float *d_a;   
   cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_a, 5*sizeof(float) );

}
```

> $ nvcc -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart -c -o
>   FSPB_main.o FSPB_main.cpp
>
> FSPB_main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>   FSPB_main.cpp:167:45: error: ‘cudaMalloc’ was not declared in this
>   scope

What does this error mean? It's just a cudaMalloc and it suppose to be supported for the compiler right?

Can functions like cudaMalloc be used in a .cpp file? Do I need to create a .cu file just for anything what comes from CUDA?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to include the header files where the CUDA functions are declared:

```
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
```

and then on the cmd line you also need to add the PATH (option `-I`) where those includes are located.

On my system, version 2.1 of CUDA installed the header files on `/usr/local/cuda`. To compile, I would do something like:

```
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart -c -o FSPB_main.o FSPB_main.cpp
```

Don't forget to add `-I.` to that command if your code depend on custom headers you wrote that are located in the same directory of the source code.

Comment: now it's #include <cuda_runtime.h>